# Finding all composites in given limits

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I want to compute all composites

$x = a^{n}$

with

$n,a \in \Bbb{N}; \\ n,a>1  $

between two given limits.

Is there a simpler way, than brute-forcing?

Answer (score 1):

Things are much easier if you are counting valid pairs of $a$ and $n$ rather than counting the actual values. (I.e. I'm assuming that you don't want to count duplicates even if the $a$ and $n$ are different). The strategy is still basically the same.

If you don't want to include duplicates, then it suffices to just use $n$ prime and then use inclusion exclusion principle to take care of duplicates. For a given $n$, say $n = 2$, if you compute the $n$th roots of your upper and lower bound then this will tell you how many squares you have in your range, without having to list them all. Then do $n = 3$, by taking cube roots of your upper and lower bound. If your range is not too large you won't have to do that many primes $n$. Then you need to subtract counts for all $n$ which are products of two of your primes, and then add counts for all $n$ that are products of three of your primes, and so forth (This is the inclusion-exclusion). If your range is numbers less than $2^k$ then the largest prime $n$ you'll need to consider is less than or equal to $k$. Also, you will probably only have to apply a few levels of inclusion-exclusion before your $n$ is too large to make $a^n$ fit in your range.

Comment: Just to clarify: I want to have an explicit list of all composites. Moreover, the range can be arbitrary large. One example: All composites between 10^64 and 10^65.

Comment: @Dschoni If you want an explicit list, then you can use a hash table to store the powers you have already found, in order to avoid duplicates. Other than that, brute force is basically all you can do. You can still take roots of your bounds to figure out what $a$ to use for given $n$.

Comment: I am taking the ceiling of log(upper_limit)/log(n) as lower limit and the floor of log(lower_limit)/log(n) as upper limit to my a so far.

Comment: @Dschoni I would have to think about it to see if that bound works. I was suggesting using $A_0^{1/n}$ and $A_1^{1/n}$ for your range of $a$ for a given $n$, if your target range you are interested In is $[A_0, A_1]$.

Comment: That's basically the same, only ceiling and floor directly is a natural number, which makes itteration afterwards easier. I'm investigating the computational cost of both approaches nevertheless.